# Dynamic default value to be selected from select dropdown in angularjs view page

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

select option should be auto selected if value match

```
<input type ="text" class="form-control  emailidinsert"  dir-paginate="emails in emailarr |  itemsPerPage:constidinfo.itemsPerPage" current-page="constidinfo.currentPage" total-items="total_count" value="{{emails.email_ids}}"  >
```

here is my text field it has value of user email.

```
<select id="editunameto" class="form-control select" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-supplier_id-container"  ng-options='unames as unames.email_id for emails in emailarr'>
      <option value="0">--Select Username--</option>
      <option ng-repeat="unames in usernames"  value="{{unames.email_id}}">{{unames.username}}</option>
</select>
```

and this is my select box want to auto select option value which is in input type text as value should match with select option value.. how can i achive i tried with ng-options but no use

Comment: It seems you are missing ng-model in your control to bind the value to the angularjs element.

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS i have added  ng-model="usernames.email_id" ng-options='unames.email_id for unames in emailarr.email_ids' in select but then also its not showing

Answer (score 0):

Please try like the below code and also check [this plunker link](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/IXTO1vYIfJUVEqFE?preview) for your sample working scenario.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.emailarr = [{
    username: 'username1',
    email_ids: 'email_Id1'
  },{
    username: 'username2',
    email_ids: 'email_Id2'
  },{
    username: 'username3',
    email_ids: 'email_Id3'
  },{
    username: 'username4',
    email_ids: 'email_Id4'
  },{
    username: 'username5',
    email_ids: 'email_Id5'
  }];
```

**Template:**

```
    <input type ="text" ng-model="emails.email_ids"/>
    <select ng-model='emails.email_ids' ng-options='emails.username as emails.email_ids for emails in emailarr'>
      <option value="">--Select Username--</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: select dropdown value comming from other query and dynamic bydefault selected value comming from other query so there is two  $scope.usernames for select box that contain username along with emailid and $scope.emailarr and this contain emailid

Comment: Changing of a scope name will be enough I think. I have updated my plunker according to your description above, Please check my [updated plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/IXTO1vYIfJUVEqFE).